# Text width not applying in span

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I can't see how to fix the span width so it doesn't wobble:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<script>   
function go() {
x='this message will self-destruct in five seconds.......';
xl=x.length;
x+=x;
n=0;
setInterval('ticker.textContent=x.slice(n++,n+10);if (n>xl-10) n=0;',100);
}  
</script>
<body onload='go();'>
<span style='background-color:red;width:100pt' id='ticker'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

A link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMarkPerry/w9ccq96x/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `span` element is an `inline` element, this means its `width` and `height` are controlled by the content, you need to use either `display:inline-block` or `display:block` depending on the wanted interaction with other elements.

Answer (score 2):

display as "block":

```
<span style='background-color:red; width:65pt; display: block' id='ticker'></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a containing div also and apply the styling to the div..

http://jsfiddle.net/w9ccq96x/1/

```
<div style="background-color:red;width:100px;overflow:hidden;"><span id='ticker'></span></div>
```