# Span element with unconstant length

Tags: javascript, html

Similar to:

[Text width not applying in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653505/text-width-not-applying-in-span)

Using the same 'span' idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
str='Just some random text that is about to be encrypted';
function go() {
    crypt.textContent=str;
}
function code() {
    sa=str.split('');
    for (i=0;i<sa.length-1;i++) if (Math.random()<0.5) {t=sa[i];sa[i]=sa[i+1];sa[i+1]=t;}
    crypt.textContent=sa.join('');
}
</script>
<body onload='go();'>
<span style='background-color:red;width:100pt' id='crypt'></span>
<button onclick='code();'>Code</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The span width still wobbles - but the text is effectively always the same length - at least the letters are the same?

[JSFiddle before](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMarkPerry/aez0njwu/)

[JSFiddle after](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMarkPerry/g9xevLad/)

Comment: what do you want.... the same width always?

Comment: i cant see why the width varies in the first place

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It does because sometimes two or more spaces end up near to each other which makes them collapse into a single space. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `span` width changing is that sometimes two or more space end up near to each other. This makes them collapse into a single space in the rendered result which reduces the amount of characters and changes the `span`’s width.

### Solution 1

Using `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) instead of a blank character will solve this. These are rendered even when there are multiple of them near to each other.

To write the `&nbsp;` character from JavaScript, you’ll need to use the corresponding escape sequence which is `\u00A0`.

```js
str='Just some random text that is about to be encrypted'.replace(/ /g, "\u00A0");
```

### Solution 2

Another (probably cleaner) solution would be to setting `white-space: pre` on the `span` element using CSS:

```
<span style="background-color: red; width: 100pt; white-space:pre" id="crypt"></span>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/